# How can I trace switch wires from 3-way switches across the room?

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I have an open concept with several 3-way and one 4-way switch.  I'm going to be adding some smart switches which will require a bit of a rewire for every switch in the series.

What's the best way to trace the wires from across the room?

I've added the wiring diagram from the manufacturer for reference.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

This is kludgy but it will work.  I turn off the power then verify that is indeed off. Then using an ohm meter on the low ohms scale I connect one lead to a long piece of loose wire that goes to the other end of the wire effectively making one of the ohm meter leads long enough to go across the room to the other switch. Then with the ohms reading I can determine which wire is which. I have also done this using the safety ground as the long lead as the other leads should not be connected to it in any way assuming the wires are removed from the switch. If it goes through the "light" that will show conduction.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just a long wire essentially.

Comment: You have it. I hope you find and solve your problems quickly.